# HBITMAP/BITMAP to BITMAPINFOHEADER -> over network - > BITMAPINFOHEADER to HBITMAP/BITMAP

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, structure

I think the title is very much explanatory but here's a bit more detail what I'm trying to do.
Basically say I have a **BITMAP loaded in Memory.**

**I would like to extract the BITMAPINFOHEADER from it** and add it to my packet structure which will be transferred over a socket.*

*Transferring it is not a problem, but once it arrives I'd like to **turn it back into a BITMAP so that I can work with it.***

I've been struggling with this and I've searched high and low without any luck. An example and a list of functions I will need to accomplish this would be helpful.

Many thanks. I need this in win32 c++. [no .NET or MFC]
Appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539874/bitmap-transfer-using-winsock-getdibits-and-setdibits http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351464/send-bitmap-with-winsock?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

Sender:

1. You have `HBITMAP`
2. Obtain its properties, such as width and height, using `GetObject`
3. Use `CreateDIBSection` to create another `HBITMAP` of the same resolution 24/32-bit RGB with `VOID*` pointer which points to raw byte; you will initialize `BITMAPINFOHEDER` in code - you should already have all data you need by that point
4. `BitBlt` from original bitmap into this one
5. Send your `BITMAPINFOHEDER` + bytes at helper bitmap data pointer to network (`sizeof BITMAPINFOHEDER` + `BITMAPINFOHEDER::biSizeImage` bytes)

Receiver:

1. Use `CreateDIBSection` to create bitmap using `BITMAPINFOHEDER` you received; you are getting again a pointer to raw data
2. `memcpy` image data into the memory location under the given pointer or just progressively receive data there
3. You have `HBITMAP` again